A local host web with localhost on port 443 was not found the site must be created in iss before can run the application
I have a configuration of .NET 2.1 LanuchSetting.json that has 2 commandNames is "IIS" then i got the error as the title above. I had changed one of them from "IIS" To "Project" and that works. But I don't know why we need to change like that.
Image afer changed

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

yep I knew why it is.
the reason is when we use IIS in configuration we have to set up a Website in IIS of window and it will work.
if we use Project, which means we use Kestrel More KesTrel of Mircrosoft
